# Is it safe to reuse Noise static keys in different handshake patterns?

Tags: noise-protocol

In the [Noise protocol](https://noiseprotocol.org), is it safe to reuse static key pairs in different handshake patterns? Like using XK to communicate between client and server, and KK to communicate between clients, but with the same static keys.